# Share Spring Boot YAML configuration between two applications

Tags: java, logging, properties, spring-boot, yaml

I have two applications in the same maven project and have given each of them their own configuration file by setting the `spring.config.name` property for each before invoking SpringApplication.run().

Thus, in the first application, I set `spring.config.name` to `server1` so it looks for `server1` instead of `application.yml`.  In the second I have set `spring.config.name` to `server2`.

However I would like them to share the same logging configuration.  Unfortunately, logging configuration cannot be imported via @PropertySource since logging is already configured before property-sources are read - see [Logging section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html) of Spring Boot manual.

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Per default Spring Boot uses the logging.file property which should be the same for both applications and hence they should use the same config. What problem do you have when adding your config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot uses as default Logback. You can put a logback.xml file in src/main/resources to configure the log. And both applications will automatically use this file to configure their logging engine.

You can learn how to configure Logback here: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

A simple example. It will set the log level to INFO and log to the Console:

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I run in this same king a deployment organization a while before. You can also refrence an external logback configuration (outside from the packaged jar/war) using the sprint-boot "logging.config" property. For example, you define define the path of your logging configuration when launching the application using the "-Dlogging.config=file:<path_to_logging_config_file>"